# Django many-to-many filtering gives "No operator matches the given name and argument types."

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have the following models in my Django project:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    faculties = models.ManyToManyField('users.Faculty', related_name='profiles')
```

Now I want to define a function that gives me all coworkers of a user/profile like so:

```
def coworkers(self):
    coworkers = User.objects.none()
    for faculty in self.faculties.all():
        coworkers |= User.objects.filter(Q(profile__faculties__id__exact=faculty.id))
    return coworkers
```

But then I always run in a `ProgrammingError at /exercise/ operator does not exist: character varying = integer` or `No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. ) was the direct cause of the following exception:`.

I also tried:

```
faculties = [f.id for f in self.faculties.all()]
coworkers = User.objects.filter(Q(profile__faculties__id__in=faculties)
```

Both versions also do not work with `__exact` instead of `__in`.

Any help?

Comment: You are missing closing `)` in queryset so it should be `User.objects.filter(Q(profile__faculties__id__in=faculties))` and I also think no need to use Q in single filtering or you can directly filter through faculties so more simplified is `User.objects.filter(profile__faculties__in=faculties)`

Comment: It should also be `class` in model not model, so please correct the typo if it is by editing the question.